# iPhone crash on synchronizing NSUserDefaults: CFPreferences Background Sync Queue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, crash, nsuserdefaults

We're seeing crashes in crashlytics that we are unable to reliably reproduce when synchronizing nsuserdefaults but it's clearly happening a lot out in the wild. They're happening in a number of different places in our app (sometimes in background threads where the stack trace doesn't include our code).

Our project uses ARC. Here's an example of one place it's happening and the code couldn't be any simpler:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:DATE_OF_LAST_MY_TEAMS_LEAGUE_SYNC];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Here's the crashlytics report:

[image: Crashlytics crash report synchronizing NSUserDefaults]

Any help in getting to the bottom of this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some other code examples where this issue occurs? And `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on a background thread immediately makes me think you are releasing (or nil-ing) an object on the main thread and then trying to access the object on a background thread. Are `weak` objects involved? But the code example given at the moment seems like it would never fail.

Comment: Having looked into this all day I think it may be a race condition in Apple's code of setting properties in one thread while synchronizing on another thread. I know the docs say it's supposed to be thread safe but this person seems to be able to reproduce this same crash reliably: https://devforums.apple.com/message/773176#773176 . I'm going to try removing most of our calls to synchronize and only do them on the main thread periodically (like in applicationWillResignActive) and then see if that helps in the next release.

Comment: @ToddH - did that have any impact on your crash logs?

Comment: @bdalziel It definitely seemed to reduce the crash volume but didn't eliminate it. Of course we use a lot of 3rd party SDK's that may be calling synchronize as well that we can't easily control.

Comment: First of all you don't need to call `synchronize` explicitly. 
Secondly if you want to, then make sure that you calling it in the main thread. This will help you to prevent the crash

Comment: Are you sure that: DATE_OF_LAST_MY_TEAMS_LEAGUE_SYNC has a value?